# Compare two objects and extract the ones that have same Key in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, object, javascript-objects

I have the following two objects

```
var productionTime= [
    {Rob3: 20},
    {Rob8: 100},
    {Rob4: 500},
    {Rob1: 100},
    {Rob5: 500}
];
var Busytime= [
    {Rob4: 10},
    {Rob3: 200},
    {Rob8: 100},
    {Rob5: 200},
    {Rob1: 100}
];
```

Now I want to divide each item in 'productionTime' by its respective 'BusyTime' which have the same key.
For example productionTime.Rob3 should be divided by BusyTime.Rob3 and  productionTime.Rob8 should be divided by BusyTime.Rob8 and so on.

How can I do this with array.find() or array.filter() in javascript/nodejs?

P.S: I know i can do it by using two nested forEach loops but that is I guess very slow

Comment: Fix the data structures (such as `var productionTime = { Rob3: 20, Rob8: 100, ... }`) and then your algorithm boils down to a single for loop.

Comment: the data structure can't change because I may have to add other keys to each object. for example. var productionTime = [
    {Rob3: 20, hasTime= "date or Time"},
    {Rob8: 100,  hasTime= "date or Time"},
    {Rob4: 500,  hasTime= "date or Time"},
    {Rob1: 100,  hasTime= "date or Time"},
    {Rob5: 500,  hasTime= "date or Time"}
];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a hash table and a single loop for every array.

```js
var productionTime = [{ Rob3: 20 }, { Rob8: 100 }, { Rob4: 500 }, { Rob1: 100 }, { Rob5: 500 }];
    busytime = [{ Rob4: 10 }, { Rob3: 200 }, { Rob8: 100 }, { Rob5: 200 }, { Rob1: 100 }],
    hash = Object.create(null);

busytime.forEach(function (o) {
    var key = Object.keys(o)[0];
    hash[key] = o[key];
});

productionTime.forEach(function (o) {
    var key = Object.keys(o)[0];
    o[key] /= hash[key];
});

console.log(productionTime);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Simple and elegant

Answer (score 1):

Convert both arrays to object using [Object#assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) and the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator). Get the keys from one of them using [Object#keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys), and iterate the keys using [Array#map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). Create a new object for each key using [shorthand property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_2015):

```js
const productionTime = [{"Rob3":20},{"Rob8":100},{"Rob4":500},{"Rob1":100},{"Rob5":500}];
const Busytime= [{"Rob4":10},{"Rob3":200},{"Rob8":100},{"Rob5":200},{"Rob1":100}];

// create objects from both arrays
const productionTimeObj = Object.assign({}, ...productionTime);
const busytimeObj = Object.assign({}, ...Busytime);

// get the keys from one of the objects, and iterate with map
const result = Object.keys(productionTimeObj).map((key) => ({ 
  // create a new object with the key, and the result of the division
  [key]: productionTimeObj[key] / busytimeObj[key]
}));

console.log(result);
```